# how to get the value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a=Array ([storage] => [submitted] => 1 [values] => Array ( [q] => googl [op]))
```

How  can I get the value of q from this array $a->q doesn't give me the value. Why?

Comment: If you are unsure of the level of nesting in an array do this :var_dump( $a ); and it will be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `->` on objects. For an array you need to index the variable like this:

```
echo $a['values']['q'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $a['values']['q'];
```

This is 2-d array you can get value like above.

you can also use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to get retrieve values of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $a['values']['q'].

Answer (score 0):

to get it do this:

```
echo $a['values']['q'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the -> on objects. For an array you need to index the variable like this:

```
echo $a['values']['q'];
```

Check this [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) tutorial for u can get more information